# How to save an intent from one class to another class

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am new to Android so apologies if I am asking something silly. I am trying to develop an alarm clock application - basically, it's my final project and I am trying to develop an alarm like there is in API level 2.3.3.

I have designed the list view that takes input through a dialog box like time. I have also coded it to set an alarm.

Now I want to save that alarm as an intent in the other class, and I don't have any idea how to save different alarms in the other activity. I have also checked for the desk-clock alarm code but I didn't get that too.

Please help me someone, I am stuck here for the code for more than a week. Please someone help me, I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: what do you mean by save ?

Comment: I can't understand what you need. Do you want to get data in the other class? Like send values to another Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an Intent from one Activity to another, and then retrieve information from inside the Intent, the best way is use the Bundle object inside the intent:

Let's supose you send the intent from Activity1 to Activity2...

In Activity 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.class,Activity2.class);
//I use the String class name as a key value, but you can use whatever key
intent.putExtra(String.class.getCanonicalName(), myString);
startActivity(intent);
//Or this other method if you want to retrieve a result from Activity2
//startActivityForResult(intent,Activity2);
```

In Activity 2:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String myString = bundle.getString(String.class.getCanonicalName());
```

Comment: @gabrielaugustodm just like in deskclock alarm when we click on the donw button after setting the alarm the alarm is save in an intent an is displayed in a listview in another activity.